# MongoClient not returning data in cucumberjs test

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, cucumber

I've taken this apart several different ways.  The find happens after the remove, and the find never finds anything.  If I comment out the `this.accounts.remove...` the find works.  If I leave the remove line in there it doesn't.  My understanding of cucumberjs, mongo client and node indicates that the find should work.

I've even tried moving the remove/find sequence into its own file, and it works there.  It seems to be only when I'm running it in cucumber that the sequence fails.  I suspect because of the way of cucumber loads the files, but I'm not sure.

Can someone help me figure out how to get this working?

World.js:

```
var db = new Db('FlashCards', new Server('localhost', 27017));

db.open(function(err, opened) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("error opening: ", err);
    done(err);
  }
 db = opened;
});

var {
  defineSupportCode
} = require('cucumber');

function CustomWorld() {

  this.db = db;
 this.accounts = db.collection('accounts');
```

hooks.js:

```
Before(function(result, done) {
  //comment this out, and leave a done(), it works!!!!
  this.accounts.remove(function(error, result){
    if( error) {
      console.log("Error cleaning the database: ", error);
      done(error);
    }
    done();
  })
});
```

user_steps.js:

```
Then('I will be registered', function(done) {
  let world = this;
  this.accounts.find({
    username: world.user.username
  }).toArray(
    function(err, accounts) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error retrieveing data: ", err);
        done(err);
      }
      console.log("Accounts found: ", accounts);
      expect(accounts).to.be.ok;
      expect(accounts.length).to.be.equal(1);
      done();
   });
});
```

Inovcation:

```
cucumber-js --compiler es6:babel-core/register
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the item to be removed  in the remove method. I am assuming the item to be removed is

this.accounts.remove(function(error, result){

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one parameter to remove method. The parameter is query to remove. I am assuming, the remove query is {username: world.user.username}

var qry={username: world.user.username};
Please try with the following:

```
Before(function(result, done) { //comment this out, and leave a done(), it works!!!!
    var qry={username: world.user.username};
     this.accounts.remove(qry, function(error, result){ 
     if( error) { 
               console.log("Error cleaning the database: ", error);
               done(error);
       } 
      done(); 
       }) });
```

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't clear enough the remove works as intended.  It's the find after that that fails.  I clear it up.